# Use grep to get slow running sql

Tags: linux, grep

i have the following line in the log file

```
D, [2015-01-09T09:10:45.625583 #10679] DEBUG -- :   GamelogDailyaccesslog Load (2.8ms)  SELECT `gamelog_dailyaccesslog`.* FROM `gamelog_dailyaccesslog` WHERE `gamelog_dailyaccesslog`.`osuser_id` = ? ORDER BY accessed_at desc LIMIT 1
```

I want to grep for queries that took more than 100ms to load. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How big is the log file? Gigabytes?

Comment: not much at most 2 GB

Comment: Where is the query time? You probably need `awk` more than just `grep`

Answer (score 2):

is log showing time always in ms? or for longer time it can use seconds etc?
if it's ms always then:

```
grep -e "([0-9]{3,}(\.[0-9]*)?ms)"
```

Comment: sorry can you remove the ","? cos it shows up like this: D, [2015-01-11T01:57:09.163028 #2441] DEBUG -- :   UserEquipment Load (18731.6ms)  SELECT `user_equipments`.* FROM `user_equipments` WHERE (`user_equipments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND `user_equipments`.`user_id` = ? AND `user_equipments`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with this output but I suppose you can change. {3,} to {3}.  ","  seems unnecessary but I made that regex in rush without testing.